# VB.NET Return Data From ListBox to TextBox using SQLDB

Tags: database, vb.net, winforms, linq, listbox

I am a bit in a stuck place. What I am trying to create, in VB.NET winforms, is a list box that has a list of names and when the user double clicks a name it return the name selected from the DB and the description of that name.

This is what I have so far, I have had many different attempts but had little to no success.

```
private Sub lstbxOfNames_DoubleClick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles lstboxOfName.DoubleClick
  Dim nameFromListBox As String = lstbxOfNames.GetItemText(lstbxOfNames.SelectedItem)
  Dim nameToTextBox as String
  txtNameDescription.Clear()
  txtName.Clear()

  With DBSet.NameTbl
    nameToTextBox = .FirstOrDefault(Function(x) x.Name = nameFromListBox).ToString()
  End With

  txtName.Text = nameToTextBox.ToString()
End Sub
```

This was the start of my code to at least return the Name from the DB. This works in a sense by not blowing up on me however, I don't get a readable result. The result I receive is projectName.dbset.Nametbl+Nametbltyperow.

Am i not supposed to use the With Statement?

Am I missing a concept here?

FYI I do not have interfaces, abstract layers, getter setters, I am using the binding object that was created when I did an "automatic" bind to the datasource in the design view.
Would I need to create all of the interfaces, abstract layers, and getter setters, in order for all this to working properly?

*****EDIT******
I am using a sql db.  The objects I am referring to is the databinding and datasources that VS creates when I setup databindings to the listbox object. However that is not what I am using in this scenario. My objective is to use the data that is returned by the listbox object.

The double click event is used to allow the user to enter into and edit mode. the Data about the name should return into the textboxes so the user can edit the data and click save to save the updated data.

Comment: Your post is confusing.  What is the DB you are actually using.  AFAIK, "SQLDB" is a Pascal related DB thing. We also dont know what "the binding object" refers to - things have names.  Rather than the `DoubleClick` event, it would be more common to use the SelectedItemChanged event.  If the control data is bound (which it sounds like it is), then you have to cast the result or you just get the type name you mentioned.

Comment: @Plutonix I am using a SQLDB. I am assuming the binding object i may be referring to is the NametblDataAdapter with a NametblBindingSource Object. I am not too familiar with how VS names and creates the binding objects. The only way I can explain what happens is the ListBox object has a visual arror that is clicked. After clicking on the arrow the DB binding wizard pops up and i would fill out; DataSourc, Disiplay Member, ValueMember.
I have chosen to use the double click event so when the user wants to edit the name they can double click on it and edit it in the text box that would I have

Comment: Re Edit: Still no idea what `a sql db` is.  A great many DBs use SQL - SQL is a language not a RDBMS and they all have names.  If the ListBox is bound to a DataSource, the item selected is all you need - no need for linq.  You might want to research *typed datasets* as that is the name of the things it sounds like you are using

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out how to solve this issue. In regards to the database confusion, I am using a MS SQL Server. I hope that is what is being asked for. The confusion comes from typically when someone is using a SQL DB I assume it is MS SQL Server. But what I have found out is the listbox object in vb.net for winforms has a method that retrieves the data from the selected list.

```
dim lstbx1 as listbox()
lstbx1.GetItemText(lstbx1.SelectedItem)
```

This will get the string of the data need will be used for a query.

What I have done is use LINQ to access the DB, however since I am using textboxes I had to create several different types of LINQ queries. If anyone know a better way please let me know.

```
dim linqQuery = from query in DBobject.Table
                Where query.column = lstbx1.GetItemText(lstbx1.SelectedItem)
                Select query.Name
textbox.text = linqQuery.FirstOrDefault.ToString()
```

I had to do this several times over on my code behind page, but I am now trying to refactor and get some stuff straight. Hopefully it works. I hope this may help anyone else who might be needing to do this.